# How to find an N number of arrays that share the most elements?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem that is analogous to the one below. Now I am sure I am not the first to come across this problem, but I have no idea what to search for or how to tackle it efficiently. What can I try?

### Problem Statement

Given an `N` number of lists, return the set of `n` lists that contain the most number of common elements.

### Example (in Python)

Suppose I have 10 lists:

```
list0 = [1, 22, 8, 3, 15, 5]
list1 = [8, -1, 16, 19, 31, 1, 4]
list2 = [1, 19, -1, 8, 4, 11]
list3 = [-2, 19, 4, 5, 6, 15, -3]
list4 = [18, 21, 2, 30]
list5 = [5, 4, 3, 19, 22, 6, 8]
list6 = [1, -1, 31, 19, 0, 9, 4]
list7 = [22, 1, 3, 5, 8, 0, 16]
list8 = [8, 22]
list9 = [4, 19, 14, 25, 22, 27, 1]

lists = [list0, list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9]
```

```
def common_lists(lists: list, n: int):
    pass
```

- When `n = 2`, `common_lists` returns `(list1, list6)` since they share `-1, 1, 4, 19, 31`
- When `n = 3`, `common_lists` returns `(list0, list5, list7)` since they share `3, 5, 8, 22`
- When `n = 4`, `common_lists` returns `(list1, list2, list6, list9)` since they share `1, 4, 19`

Comment: Please make an attempt, ask a specific question, and include a [mre]. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, so asking a question as broad as this is not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach would be to check each combination of n lists:

```
from itertools import combinations
def common_lists(lists,n):
    nums   = set().union(*lists)
    result = max(combinations(lists,n),key=lambda c:len(nums.intersection(*c)))
    return result, nums.intersection(*result)
```

output:

```
common_lists(lists,2)

[1, 22, 8, 3, 15, 5]     # list0
[22, 1, 3, 5, 8, 0, 16]  # list7
{1, 3, 5, 8, 22}         # 5 in common

common_lists(lists,3)

[1, 22, 8, 3, 15, 5]     # list0
[5, 4, 3, 19, 22, 6, 8]  # list5
[22, 1, 3, 5, 8, 0, 16]  # list7
{8, 3, 5, 22}            # 4 in common

common_lists(lists,4)

[8, -1, 16, 19, 31, 1, 4]   # list1
[1, 19, -1, 8, 4, 11]       # list2
[1, -1, 31, 19, 0, 9, 4]    # list6
[4, 19, 14, 25, 22, 27, 1]  # list9
{1, 19, 4}                  # 3 in common
```